# Generate Navigation Bar View by Code (Not using Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to code **without** using Storyboard or Interface Builder in my project. So, in the need of create a side menu for my app, I want to create a Navigation Bar to give the chance to open the menu by tapping on the left button of my navigation Bar.

This is what I have tried with no success:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  centerViewController = ViewController()
  centerViewController.delegate = self

  centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
  let menuButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "TMDB", style: .plain, target: centerViewController, action: Selector(("toggleLeftButton")))
  centerNavigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
  view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
  addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

  centerNavigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

My Navigation Bar is not showing any button nor title.

Comment: Pagan CHECK THIS ONCE-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793331/creating-a-navigationcontroller-programatically-swift

Comment: Thanks for answering. Not working. I have tried in my AppDelegate adding my code to generate the button too, and still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem was where I was writting the code. It must be instantiated inside the viewController where the NavigationController belongs.

I mean, inside the **centerViewController** not in his parent as I was doing.

This lines of code:

```
let menuButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "TMDB", style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("toggleLeftButton")))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

Inside the controller  ViewController.

**EDIT**

Reference:

> [Adding UIBarButtonItem to UINav..Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520912/adding-uibarbuttonitem-to-uinav-controller)

Answer (score 1):

I know that is no longer necessary but still. His lessons are helpfull https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS-CCd4xmRY